# Find $f \circ g$ of $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, relations

Let $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x + 2$. Domain is all real numbers for both. Need to find $f \circ g$ and simplify the equation as much as possible.

Am I correct in understanding that the $f \circ g$ will be $f(g(x)) = x^2+2$? And how can I simplify it further?

PS: Apologies for such a rudimentary question. I have returned to college and am taking a basic maths class

**EDIT:** Thanks to Brian's comment realized $f \circ g$ will be  $x^2 + 4x + 4$.

Comment: It seems to me that you've written out $g(f(x)) = g(x^2) = x^2+2$.  Maybe write it out step by step; first write out $f(g(x)) = f(x+2)$, and go on from there.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I have calculated the fog to be x^2 + 4x + 4. I still dont see how this can be further simplified apart from writing this is (x+2) (x+2).

Comment: @Code_starter Yes, that's correct : it can't be simplified further.  If you are taking a math class, please use the "related links" bar on the right to visit questions related to this topic. MSE is a repository, so there are plenty of questions of the kind you have just asked, including [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895706/find-domain-and-range-of-f-circ-g-for-fx-ln-x-and-gx-x2%e2%88%921?rq=1) and the questions linked to it. You'll find plenty of joy searching on this site.

Comment: Incidentally, if you're getting back into the mathematical swing of things, you should take the time to learn MathJax/LaTeX for asking questions here.  Many times, it's quite simple; for instance, enclosing your `x^2 + 4x + 4` in dollar signs (like this: `$x^2 + 4x + 4$`) yields $x^2+4x+4$.  Other special symbols have their "backslash codes": `$f \circ g \equiv f(g(x))$` yields $f \circ g \equiv f(g(x))$.

Comment: Here is a subtle point about functions. Technically, $f$ is the function—the thing that maps each input to its output. By contrast, $f(x)$ is the value of the function at the point $x$. $f(x)$ is just a real number, not a function. So when people say 'consider the function $f(x)=x^2$', this is just an abbreviation of 'consider the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ for all real $x$'. As you can see, the latter statement is rather cumbersome, and so we often use the former statement, despite the loss of logical precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $f(x)=x^2$ tells us that the function $f$ squares its input. So
$$
f(\text{something)}=\text{something}^2
$$
Here, the "something" is $g(x)$, so
$$
f(g(x))=g(x)^2=(x+2)^2=x^2+4x+4 \, .
$$
The function $f\circ g$ is simply the function such that, for all $x$, $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x)) \, .$ So we can also write this as
$$
(f\circ g)(x)=x^2+4x+4 \, .
$$
Note that $f\circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are not the same function in general. In this case, $g$ is the "add $2$" function, and so
$$
g(f(x))=f(x)+2=x^2+2 \, .
$$
You seem to have got $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ confused. Remember that $(f \circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$ means "apply the function $f$ to the input $g(x)$", whereas $(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$ means "apply the function $g$ to the input $f(x)$". I hope that helps.